# How to solve handlebar partials are not supported in VS Code?

Tags: express, visual-studio-code, handlebars.js, prettier

I am using handlebars as templeting engine for my project. I am using prettier for formatting but during formatting hbs file i am getting error as **SyntaxError: Handlebars partials are not supported** . I tried to find solution on internet but failed.

Here is complete log of error:

```
SyntaxError: Handlebars partials are not supported: 

(error occurred in 'an unknown module' @ line 2 : column 2) (2:2)

  1 |

  2 |   {{> header}}

    |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^

  3 |         <header>

  4 |           <nav class="navbar">

  5 |             <a href="#" style="display: inline-block">

at n (c:\Users\Admin\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode

9.0.0\node_modules\prettier\parser-glimmer.js:1:1320)

at Object.parse (c:\Users\Admin\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode

9.0.0\node_modules\prettier\parser-glimmer.js:1:183895)

at Object.parse$a [as parse] (c:\Users\Admin\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode

9.0.0\node_modules\prettier\index.js:12513:19)
```

My code is:

```
{{> header}}
     <header>
       <nav class="navbar">
         <a href="#" style="display: inline-block">
           <object
             data="./images/background.png"
             width="100"
             height="80"
             style="pointer-events: none"
           ></object>
         </a>
         <div class="navbar_search">
           <input
             type="text"
             name="search-bar"
             id="search"
             placeholder="Search..."
             maxlength="15"
           />
           <a href=""
             ><i data-feather="search" class="navbar_search-icon"></i
           ></a>
         </div>
         <div class="navbar_icons">
           <a href=""><i data-feather="bell"></i></a>
           <a href=""><i data-feather="user"></i></a>
           <a href=""><i data-feather="settings"></i></a>
         </div>
       </nav>
     </header>
     <br></br>
      <h1 class="heading_pink" align = "center">WHAT TO DO AFTER 12TH?</h1>
      <hr  color = "black">
       <section class="chain">
       <ul class="chain_list">
         <li class="chain_list-item">TIP 1</li>
         <li class="chain_list-item">TIP 2</li>
         <li class="chain_list-item">TIP 3</li>
         <li class="chain_list-item">TIP 4</li>
         <li class="chain_list-item">TIP 5</li>
          <li class="chain_list-item">TIP 6</li>
           <li class="chain_list-item">TIP 7</li>
       </ul>
     </section>
    {{> footer}}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a prettierrc configuration that formats the partials the right way

For more details see https://github.com/shpp/programming.org.ua/issues/25

filename: .prettierrc.json

content:

```json
{
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "printWidth": 100,
  "useTabs": false,
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "endOfLine": "lf",
  "arrowParens": "always",
// IMPORTANT PART BELLOW
  "overrides": [   
    {
      "files": "**/*.hbs",
      "options": {
        "parser": "angular"   
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This worked best for me. Thanks! The solution above of using the glimmer parser worked ok, but it replaced all double quotes with single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Old question but ran into this and thought was worth posting here, if you are using handlebars with prettier, configure your `.hbs` files to use the Glimmer parser in your `.prettierrc` file, like so:

```json
{
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": "**/*.{hbs}",
            "options": {
                "parser": "glimmer"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If you dont have a `.prettierrc` file, create one in the root of your project with the contents above, and you should be good to go.

This way all your templates also get properly formatted, better than ignoring them.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not help... Any other hints?

Comment: Hm maybe this is linked to:
https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/11834#

Comment: @Merc yes, **Glimmer** is made for Ember so it does not support partials, so it gives you errors when formatting files which import partials, but in my case I prefer to user [handlerbars-layouts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars-layouts) anyways, which gives you blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [.prettierignore](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#ignoring-files-prettierignore) file to ignore templates.

```sh
# if your files are in a templates folder for example
# add this folder to the .prettierignore
templates
```

On the same docs page is also a [section about handlebars](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#handlebars). If you prefer to ignore only parts of your file you can follow this.

```html
{{! prettier-ignore }}
<div>
  "hello! my parent was ignored"
  {{#my-crazy-component     "shall"     be="preserved"}}
    <This
      is  =  "also preserved as is"
    />
  {{/my-crazy-component}}
</div>
```

Comment: When using  {{! prettier-ignore }} I still get the error. Very confusing.