# VS Code and Handlebars formatting unable to get partials on new lines

Tags: handlebars.js, visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-vscode

after a PC crash I was luckily able to recover data but not programs and settings. Now using VS Code + Prettier I'm not able to have multiple Handlebars partials to new lines. Eg:

```
{{> Partial_1}}
{{> Partial_2}}
```

on save it becomes:

```
{{> Partial_1}} {{> Partial_2}}
```

Can't find the solution (or maybe I'm not asking the right question to Google)...

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with Prettier & handlebar files. From your example, it seems that you are using HTML Language Features as the formatter.
Try setting this in your VS Code `settings.json` file

```
"html.format.indentHandlebars": true
```

You can however right-click the `.hbs` file and select the option *Format Document With* to choose Prettier. You can also set Prettier as the default formatter for handlebar files but currently, Prettier uses the Glimmer parser for handlebar files which does not support partials so your codes won't be formatted properly.

See the related issue on Github: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/11834

Possible workaround: [How to solve handlebar partials are not supported in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70031052/how-to-solve-handlebar-partials-are-not-supported-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 0):

I put bellow code in my settings.json and I got **some** Prettier format and red background on Prettier button is gone away.

```
"[handlebars]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
}
```